# $U$ subset of $S$, $G$ acts transitively on $S$, show that the subsets $gU$ cover $S$ evenly

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a finite set $S$ on which a group $G$ acts transitively. Now, I let $U$ be a subset of $S$. I want to show that the subsets $gU$ cover $S$ evenly, meaning every element of $S$ is in the same number of sets $gU$.

**My Thoughts:** I know that $G$ acts transitively on $S$ so there is one orbit. Can I just let $p: X_s \rightarrow X_t$ defined by $gU \rightarrow (xg)U$ where $s,t \in S$ such that $xs=t$? I know that this map is injective and surjective? Is there a more straight forward approach? I am having some trouble seeing this in an easy manner. Thanks!

Comment: You pretty much already have a solution, and the most straightforward.   The set $X_s$ is the set of all $gU$ that contain $s$.  You wanted to show that for any other $t \in S$ that $X_t$, the elements $gU$ that contain $t$,  and $X_s$ have the same number of elements.   That is, show $X_s$ has the same cardinality as $X_t$.     You defined a map between the sets that is a bijection which proves they do.

Comment: Thanks Danny I understand this approach, but was just wondering if I could do it in an even easier way! However, this works! Thanks!!